# HTAccess Rewriting Search Query String to Pretty URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read other threads to configure the result below. The problem I'm having is that the url contains the 'local' server as well.

I have a Search URL of:

```
https://www.example.com/news/?s=recipe
```

(can be "recipe", "article", "news", "place", etc).

Required output result:

```
https://www.example.com/news/search/recipe/
```

Part of the problem is that there will NOT always be a search query parameter available to the News page URL, so will have to incorporate that into the Rewriting code.

```
## Rewrite the Search s= to an SEO friendly output
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteBase /
# external redirect from action URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news/\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ news/search/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
#
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^news/search/([^/.]+)/?$/ news/?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: what is the problem, can you explain more?

Comment: @Ben, the URL that is written also contains the absolute server folder directories definition, e.g. htdocs/home/123/domain/ etc.., plus the actual website server name.

Comment: you should comment out this line `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @Ben I already have done, no success, thanks.

Comment: @anubhava I get a 404 Error if I uncomment "RewriteBase /". if I leave as commented out i still get a 404 but with the server folder list: https://www.example.com/kunden/homepages/25/d694321249/htdocs/example/news/search/recipe

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? It is not directly under site root directory?

Comment: @anubhava it is a shared server with multiple domains hosted so the .htaccess file is located in the domain subfolder off the root of the server.

Comment: Then change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /subfolder/` and retest from a new browser.